# FDTD solution vs fresnel equation solutiom for reflectivity

Tags: optics, waves, semiconductor-physics, computational-physics, diffraction

[image]
I am comparing reflectance intensity of silicon structure with a hole.

I am getting oscillating solution for 0 roughness factor in equation based model, but the spectrum shape of FDTD and equation based model solution starts matching if I increase the roughness factor.
Does this mean there is some default roughness factor in FDTD numerical solution?
[image]
[image: 1]
[image]

Comment: Hello aawer and welcome to Physics SE. I am not sure this is the best SE site to post your question. Maybe you could get better off at the Computational Science SE (https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) as they are more into numerical formulations (such as the FDTD you are using). I may be wrong though since your question is indeed related to a physical quantity but there may very well be another problem in your model (of numerical nature).

Comment: @ZaellixA [tag:computational-physics] questions are on topic on this site

Comment: @aawer: It might be beneficial for you to include the equation you are modeling, as FDTD is a generic term indicating a method instead of a formula.

Comment: @KyleKanos thanks, i have added the equation that i used in matlab. The FDTD solution is from lumerical.

Comment: @KyleKanos I didn't suggest the question is off-topic, I just mentioned that it may be more appropriate for the Computational Science SE. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @ZaellixA thank you, i didn't know about that forum. i have posted there as well.

Comment: @KyleKanos and why there's slight shift in curve with change in height in fdtd solution